# Gnome lock Screen

Tags: gnome, screen, lock

I have installed Ubuntu 13.04 Gnome shell version.  When locking the screen I get the clock in the middle with the desktop icons in the back ground.  I would like to know if there is any way to change this so the icons would not show on the lock screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot searching I found the answer to this question.

• Go into user accounts and setup the main user to login automatically.
• Restart the system.
• Lock the screen using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> the screen changes to a plain desktop without the icons.
• Go back into the user account and reactivate the login with password.
• Reboot the system and the problem should be solved.